# FloatingLabelComboBox can't seem to set binding data to codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a project in order to create a custom control that binds properties to display the properties of the selected item.

For example, I have two instances of my CustomControl, one for "StudentName" and the other for "Student's BloodGroup." For StudentName, I want to bind it to StudentName, and for the BloodGroup, I want to use .

**Q1: Why FloatingLabelComboBox can't to set binding data to codebehind.**

**Q2: how can i set second ComboBox SelectedItem match with SelectedItem of first ComboBox .**

FloatingLabelComboBox :

```cs
  public class FloatingLabelComboBox : ComboBox
  {
        static FloatingLabelComboBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox)));
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata("LabelText"));

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelForegroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.AliceBlue));

        public Brush LabelForeground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(LabelForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelForegroundProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelFontSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));

        public double LabelFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(LabelFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

  }
```

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:materialdesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FloatingLabelComboBox"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:FloatingLabelComboBox.CustomControls">
    
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:FloatingLabelComboBox }">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type  custom:FloatingLabelComboBox }">
                    <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding LabelForeground}"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding LabelFontSize}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                               Margin="-5 0 0 0" />

                        <ComboBox x:Name="textBox" 
                                     ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                  SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"
                                
                               DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                                
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  materialdesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
                                  materialdesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="Dark"
                                  materialdesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="0.10"
                                  materialdesign:HintAssist.FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

StudentModel :

```cs
 public class StudentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _studentId;
        public int StudentId
        {
            get => _studentId;
            set
            {
                if (value == _studentId) return;
                _studentId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_studentId));
            }
        }

   
    private string _studentName;
    public string StudentName
    {
      get => _studentName;
      set
      {
        _studentName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _bloodgroup;
    public ObservableCollection<string> BloodGroup
    {
      get => _bloodgroup;
      set
      {
        _bloodgroup = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

      }
```

```xml
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
       <StackPanel Margin="30" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80">
            <custom:FloatingLabelComboBox Width="160" 
                                         LabelText="Student" 
                                         Foreground="AliceBlue" 
                                         LabelForeground="LimeGreen"
                                         materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="Student"
                                         FontSize="20"   
                                         LabelFontSize="13"
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"  
                                          DisplayMemberPath="StudentName"    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                       
            />
            <custom:FloatingLabelComboBox Width="160" 
                                         Margin="40 0 0 0"
                                         LabelText="Blood Group" 
                                         Foreground="AliceBlue" 
                                         LabelForeground="LimeGreen"
                                         materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="Blood Group"
                                         FontSize="20"
                                         LabelFontSize="13"   ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStudent.BloodGroup}"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBloodGroup,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"     />
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Categories" Width="100"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" Foreground="White"  Width="100"  Height="50" DisplayMemberPath="StudentName"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Proucts" Width="100"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStudent.BloodGroup}" Width="100"  Height="50"  Foreground="White"   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBloodGroup}"   />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    
    public ViewModel()
    {
      this.Students = new ObservableCollection<StudentModel>()
            { new StudentModel(){ StudentName = "Jane", BloodGroup = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "A", "B", "AB", "0"  }},
              new StudentModel(){ StudentName = "Jone",  BloodGroup = new ObservableCollection<string>()  { "A", "B", "AB", "0" }},
              new StudentModel(){ StudentName = "Tina", BloodGroup = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"A", "B", "AB", "0"}}
            };
    

      this.SelectedStudent = Students.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<StudentModel> Students { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> BloodGroups { get; private set; }


    public StudentModel _selectedStudent;
    public StudentModel SelectedStudent
    {
      get { return _selectedStudent; }
      set
      {
        _selectedStudent = value;
        if (_selectedStudent != null)
        {
          BloodGroups = _selectedStudent.BloodGroup;
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BloodGroups));
        }

        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public string _selectedBloodGroup ;
    public string SelectedBloodGroup
    {
      get { return _selectedBloodGroup; }
      set
      {
        _selectedBloodGroup = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: You should encounter some XAML designer errors. For example, SelectedValue is a read-only property that you can't assign a Binding to. It's read-only and returns the value specified by the SelectedValuePath property. You set this property to point to a property in the SelectedItem. Then you can bund SelectedItem to your data context (it's TwoWay by default). And don't forget to remove the illegal SelectedValue binding from the internal ComboBox and the FloatingLabelComboBox.

Comment: Next, your OnPropertyChanged is called with the backing field's name as the argument, but it must be the property name. In your case you don't have to specify that argument explicitly,. Call the invocatir the way you did it for the BloodGroup property - without any argument. And your FloatingLabelComboBox definitely should extend the ComboBox class and not Control. This way you don't have to mirror the ComboBox API. You still can override the default style. This will also eliminate the ComboBox from the ControlTemplate and therefore remove the illegal Bindung declaration.

Comment: Lastly, when you went to display a small string value, don't use the Label control. Instead use the TextBlock control as it is optimized for this scenario. You should replace the Label in your ControlTemplate with a TextBlock.

Comment: Hi,@BionicCode. I assign Student = Students.FirstOrDefault(); to the binding of SelectedItem. When the window is displayed, the Combobox is empty and no value is selected. When Debug changes and selects other options, nothing happens and the set method of public StudentModel Student is not entered.

Comment: Hi,@BionicCode.I updated my question, please check it out.